# Extensive form game with multiple players

Tags: microeconomics, game-theory, extensive-games

I am wondering on how to draw the extensive form with multiple players. Below is an example of the trust game. How would that look if there were two receivers with potentially different payoffs? Note that the proposer can choose to send to both, none, or either one of the players. More specifically, I am wondering how many branches I would have in the first stage when the proposer decides. Four?

[image]

Comment: ...yes? Trust both, trust A, trust B, trust no one. Not sure where the confusion is.

Comment: One potential complication is *how much* to send to each of the two trustees when the proposer trusts both. Another condition to specify is whether the trustees get to see what the proposer decides (i.e. do they know if the other trustee is sent money or not). This latter point may not affect the game's outcome but it'll matter when you draw the game tree.

Comment: Indeed, one problem is that offer of player is continuous, so the branch where they decide to offer to both looks horrible.